# Old emails still open even after being logged out of Gmail

Tags: gmail, logout

My tablet was stolen, so I've logged out of my Google account on all devices and changed my password. But when I test it on my other tablet, my emails still open even though it's not logged in. The tablet tells me that I need to sign in, and I can't send emails, but all the emails that were already in the app are readable.

How do I fix it?

That means whoever stole my tablet can read all my old emails?

Comment: Were you using an email client (like the Microsoft Outlook desktop application), one that utilizes IMAP or POP3? These programs download the mail from the server to your computer/device (each a little differently). Check which one you are using on your tablets. If you were using POP, then whoever stole your tablet can almost definitely read all of the mail on that tablet. With IMAP, maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *My Account - Sign-in & Security - Device Activity & notifications* and remove those devices or break the sessions or whatever it says.